# How to make canvas move with HTML5 feature only?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events, draggable

I want to move the shape that I draw with the canvas; for example: I draw rectangle. How I can move it to specific area with drag-able attribute? Also using Javascript how to add the listener?

Waiting for help.

This is my code :

In Javascript file:

```
var c=document.getElementById("rectangle");
var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
cxt.fillStyle="#009933";
cxt.fillRect(20,10
,150,75);


function dragStart(ev) {
//allow move
ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect='move';

//on transfer
var style = ev.target.getAttribute("id").style;
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.getAttribute("id"));
//ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,0,0);
ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - ev.clientX) ,(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - ev.clientY));
return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {

return true;
}
function dragOver(event) {
event.preventDefault();
return false;
}
function dragDrop(ev) {
//var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
   var dm = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
   // dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
   // dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
 ev.target.appendChild(dm); 
 ev.stopPropagation();  
ev.preventDefault();
    return false;

}
```

HTML File:

```
<div  ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" 
     ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" 
     ondragover="return dragOver(event)">
<canvas id="rectangle" width="200px" height="150px" draggable="true"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="target"ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" 
     ondrop="return dragDrop(event)" 
     ondragover="return dragOver(event)">

</div>
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: I can move the canvas in firefox in to specific area but not in specific postion in this area. also I can move it back to its postion. Using javascript. This will be done with firefox but chrome will show the highlight for the backgroung of the canvas during moving. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: Post the relevant parts of the code you’re working on.

Answer (score 1):

### HTML5 Canvas Basics

First, let us discuss the manner in which the HTML5 Canvas works. Like a real-world canvas with fast-drying oil paints, when you `stroke()` or `fill()` or `drawImage()` onto your canvas the paint becomes part of the canvas. Although you drew a 'rectangle' and see it as such, the pixels of the rectangle completely replaced the background (or in the case of anti-aliasing at the edges of the rectangle, blended with and forever changed them). What would Monet say if you asked him to 'move' one of the people in a painting a little bit to the right? You can't move the rectangle, you can't drag the rectangle, you can't erase the rectangle, you can't detect a mouseover of the rectangle…because **there is no rectangle**, there is just a single 2D array of pixels.

### "Dragging" on HTML5 Canvas

What you can do (must do) is track mouse movements yourself, clear and redraw the canvas with the rectangle at different spots as you 'drag' it.

Comment: I use dragging and I set image to the canvas ....so it is work.. but drawing the image for every postion ... it will be slow process..

Comment: @Javalover You underestimate how fast computers are. Here is a demo of [20 small images being redrawn at over 200fps](http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_sprites_canvas.html), and another [much larger image being redrawn at over 150fps](http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_speed_canvas.html). (Speed depending on your computer.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/

Comment: You might be misunderstanding what the HTML 5 canvas object allows. Once you draw a rectangle on it - that rectangle becomes static image data on the canvas and is not a separate object that you can reference. You would have to do something where you track the mousedown and mouseup events and constantly re-draw the rectangle based on the mouse cursor position to fake the "drag" effect.

Comment: I know ... but I want to use HTML5 only. but the problem in dragging the element ... it drag not to mouse position.

Comment: From your code, it appears that you are dragging the entire canvas, not a rectangle shape within a canvas - is that correct? Do you want to move the canvas from one div to another or move a shape within a canvas?

Comment: That tutorial only worked for me in Firefox and it's dragging div's between other div's - not canvas objects. You might want to look at this instead: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/

Comment: I do not want  to use Javascript libaray ... Only HTML5 ... ok lets say I want to move canves what about its correct postion ??? where mouse down

Comment: @Javalover You do not understand what HTML5 is, or what the technologies involved do.